# How to attach the Kotlin sources to android library project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I have an android library project (.aar file, not .jar), and attaching java sources with task

```
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}
```

But kotlin fource files are not showing up for users of my library. How can I add kotlin source files as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

And it will add kotlin sources as well.

---

For .jar library, you can use

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSources
}
```

instead of

```
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
```